# How to easyily find unused public methods/properties

Tags: .net, properties, methods, refactoring, public-method

I have a .Net(C#) solution. The solution contains bunch of projects. The projects were implemented not by me. It is not a framework, it means that I need to have amount of public methods/properties as less as possible. My task is to identify methods and properties which are not used, but exist in the projects. Well, I can find private methods which are not used using R#. But it is completely unclear how to find *public* methods/properties which are not used.

I heard that they have NDepend tool, but it is not very simple tool, is it.

So, the question is: could you please point to a tool which can be used to identify methods which are not used in a solution. It is OK with me to have command line tool or something pretty simple.

UPD: I tried to use trial NDepend.

Well, first of all it seems like it is possible to see public methods (properties are represented as get_ set_ methods) which are not used in this particular assembly.

But NDepend does not recognize if the public method is used from another project/assembly, which is a part of the solution and shows the method as unused. But this is not true.

UPD2: mcintyre321 advised to use R#. Please read a first comment below.

Comment: Just make sure what you decide to remove isn't being called via Reflection!

Comment: Thank you for the note. I am sure that reflection is not used in my solution. But webservices are :-\

Comment: I've removed the image link as it appears to be dead and was directing to a nons https url

Answer (score 8):

If you turn on solution wide analysis in ReSharper (5.0 and above) it will flag them for you. This includes public methods.

- [Explanation of Solution-Wide analysis](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html#Solution-Wide_Analysis)
- [How to enable](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Solution-Wide_Analysis__Enabling_Solution-Wide_Analysis.html)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately, it did not help. In the end R# just show that some css and asxc paths were not found/valid. But it did not say anyting about public methods/properties.

Comment: Thank you for the picture.  "Errors in Solution" list has no errors and this is exactly what I had. Now I understand what you meant and think it can help. Is it possible to get a list with all unused methods in the solution in one "window" using R#, for instance in Error List?

Comment: You can configure the inspection severity in R# options so that they show up as warnings or errors.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Unfortunately, R# does not show (at least for me) public unused methods as errors, but shows private ones. I have R# 4.5. Does it show them for you?

Comment: Resharper menu => Options => Code Inspection => Inspection Severity => Unused Declaration => Non-private accessibility = Show as error

Comment: In fact, you can set loads of different Resharper suggestions as warnings on the Inspection Severity tab. You should be able to get the settings you want by manipulating those settings.

Comment: This is just what I did, but it does not work for me. As you can see in the original question screenshot (I added it after your suggestions), the unused method is highlighted as error (in red), because I did like you said. But "Errors in Solution" window does not show unused public method as error even when I have the setting enabled. Could you please do the same on your side and attach a screenshot?

Comment: Resharper 5 DOES show errros in solution. See the link in my answer for a pre-release build

Answer (score 0):

Heck I have done it old school.  I just comment out methods I don't think are being used and build.  If I get an error, then I leave it there.

Comment: But it is not a good way to solve the issue if you have pretty much classes. In this case it is a lot of work. We are programmers here and need to think how to automate the process.

Thank you.

Comment: Also you only get errors if the method is being directly referenced, which is not always the case, e.g. for event subscribers in a IoC container