# How to detect uncalled public methods?

Tags: c#, code-analysis

You can setup Visual Studio 2017 code analysis with rule CA1811 to warn you avoid uncalled private methods, but how can I get warnings about uncalled public methods?  I mean that they're not called across the entire solution.  For my purposes, I can assume that this means the code is never called because I am not exposing any of these assemblies outside this solution.

Comment: But if you're not exposing them externally, why are they public to begin with?

Comment: They were previously used by other assemblies in the same solution but now many of them are no longer referenced.

Comment: Get JetBrains Resharper....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to easy find unused public methods/properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471855/how-to-easy-find-unused-public-methods-properties)

Comment: Looks like re-sharper does it if your prepared to pay the (hefty) price tag for that one piece of funtionality

Comment: @Flater They could have been referenced by other assemblies in the solution? How else would you do that without public?

Comment: So paying for Resharper is the only way?  That's very annoying.  Surely they could've added this as a rule in Visual Studio code analysis easily!!

Comment: If you just need it for a one off, get the Resharper trial, remove all your unused methods, and then uninstall Resharper once the trial expires.  That being said, Resharper should be considered a must have development tool IMO.

Comment: Resharper is not the only way; the other way would be to *write an analyzer*.  Some humans wrote R# and VS code analysis; you're human; you could write your own analyzer. Plus: writing code analyzers is fun.

Comment: @Jez: Checking Google, a bunch of people have written Roslyn functions to find unused methods.  Adapting them to suit your purposes should be possible.  Just be warned that, unlike Resharper, Roslyn analyzers have a bad habit of ignoring markup files.  Also note that it's impossible for a static analyzer to reliably find method calls made via reflection.